# On() doesn't find prepended HTML

Tags: jquery, prepend

There are several posts dealing with `on()` and DOM elements added through JavaScript, but none see to apply to my situation.

After `<li class="prepend"><a href="#">x</a></li>` is prepended inside a `<ul>`, I can't seem to attach events to it.

**JS:**

```
$('.categories > li a').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).parent().is('.more')) {
        $(this).siblings('ul').prepend('<li class="back"><a href="#">&lt; ' + $(this).html() + '</a></li>')
    }  else if ($(this).parent().is('.back')) {
        console.log('it worked')
    }
})
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="categories">
    <li class="selected">
        <a href="#">1 Featured</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">1 Popular Genres</a>
    </li>
    <li class="more">
        <a href="#">1 My Rooms &gt;</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">2 Tristique Cras</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2 Porta Etiam &gt;</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2 Mattis Tortor</a></li>
            <li class="more">
                <a href="#">2 Cras Fermentum &gt;</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">3 Tristique Cras</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3 Porta Etiam</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3 Mattis Tortor</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3 Cras Fermentum</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Even this simple event won't see clicks to elements with class `.back`

```
$('a').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this);
})
```

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for the three-argument variant of `on` that uses delegation to handle dynamically-added elements? `$(parent).on(eventType, targetSelector, handler)`, e.g., `$('.categories').on('click', 'li a', function() { });`

Comment: @apsillers I'm not sure I understand the difference. One bubbles up only one level, and one is document-wide. Shouldn't I at least be seeing something/anything in console log?

Comment: @apsillers btw, this does work, but I don't understand why.

Comment: When you run `$('.categories > li a')` you select all the elements *currently on the page* that match your selector, and attach listeners to them. Elements that are added later don't get selected (unless you run another selector and attach more events). The three-arg variant `on` works on a *container* and says, "*Hey container, if any of your **descendants** ever get clicked (regardless of when they were added), here's how to handle that event.*"

Comment: See [Direct vs. Delegated - jQuery .on()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110934/direct-vs-delegated-jquery-on) for a good explanation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic html page creation with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407808/dynamic-html-page-creation-with-jquery)

Comment: +1 to @apsillers you explained the problem perfectly!

Comment: this is not the same as $(this)

Comment: @apsillers Thanks, that makes sense! One question: I see a lot of people selecting document instead of a child container. Is there a reason I should use a container further down the DOM?

Comment: I'll answer you...
the reason is a single question of speed.
Imagine that if you enter "document" he goes to look again at all the DOM in search of new elements, while if you're sure that the new elements must be searched only within a container element, then you can enter that in order as to speed up the search for new elements.
I hope I explained well ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watch this:
http://jsfiddle.net/lughino/8uzgd/

in order to capture the elements that are created after the page loads, you need to call on method in this way:

```
$(document).on('click', '.categories > li a', function(event){
```

To learn more take a look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: While this may work, there isn't any explanation as to why. I guess it seems implicit that if I'm using the feature that I have at least tried to understand the docs on `on()`, so it would have been better if you had tried an alternative explanation.

Comment: Thank you for reporting.
In fact I wanted to add it to the answer but then I saw in the comments that I had already explained and I did not want to repeat myself!